# How is root able to write to the sudoers file with permissions set to 440?

Tags: files, permissions

So when I look at the permissions of the /etc/sudoers file, it is like so

```
-r--r----- 1 root root 705 Nov  2 19:57 /etc/sudoers
```

Now, wouldn't this mean it's not writable? So how does the root user manage to write to it?

Comment: security reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root user has always full write access to any file, regardless of its mode.

Perhaps the best example is `/etc/shadow`, which is mode 000 but of course modifiable by root:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# ls -pl /etc/shadow
----------. 1 root root 1353 Oct 26 07:40 /etc/shadow
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments the original answer was kind of unclear.

The owner of a file can always change the permissions of any file he owns (while root can do this for all existing files).

If you are a regular user it depends on the way you try to modify the read-only-file:

- open the file with vi and change it -> you can write the changes with ":w!"
- try #echo "test" >> read-only-file there is a permission denied.

If you are the root user you can overwrite and change any file you want, but the program vi will consider the read-only-permissions and ask for a confirmation.

The file /etc/sudoers should always be changed by the "visudo"-command, which opens the content of the actual file in a temporary file, and does some checks before saving the changes. As root-User the changes can be written despite the read-only-permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use visudo instead of vi

```
sudo visudo
```